# Why occur ValueError in my simple code in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R9GT.png)

here is my code

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

print(a, b)
```

and run result is here.

```
C:\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/PycharmProjects/main.py
1
10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i just input 5(enter)10
but error has occurred

in debug mode, it is OK
Why occur ValueError in code??
please refer to attached picture also.
thanks..!!

Comment: Looks like a problem with input in PyCharm. If you ran this code in a terminal it would work fine.

Comment: Looking again, it appears that somehow / somewhere the input function is getting an *empty string*, which is throwing the error when being converted to an int.  Test this with `int('')`, which throws the same error.

Comment: @S3DEV

like this? 

a = int('')
b = int('')

print(a, b)

C:\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/PycharmProjects/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @khelwood Yes, it is success in terminal.

Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = int(input())
5
>>> b = int(input())
10
>>> print(a,b)
5 10
>>>